# jQuery : trying to draw elements that snap together and break apart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement some kind of very basic flow chart functionality in a div.
Basically I have some boxes which by default my be joined by a little AND bubble. If I click on the bubble it will change to an OR bubble which will result in the boxes (divs) splitting.

Not really to sure where to start on this any guidance much appreciated - eg links to something similar or advice in what to look into.  I've attached a mockup to help explain what I mean.

Thanks as always SO

W
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward. Bind a `click` on the and/or button, which changes the CSS class of the lower box to a class which has a larger `margin-top` property and moves the `background-position` of the and/or image to show OR. You could use jQuery's `toggle` function for this, though I imagine you'll be storing the state in a separate data structure anyway.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I might be able to get the (AND) button to kinda sit on the center bottom of the box ?

Comment: @wmitchell You could do that in various ways with CSS. The most straightforward would be to set the containing element (the titlebar or the whole window) to relative, and use absolute positioning. The specific solution depends on the HTML and CSS structure you're using.  You could have it underneath the top box, and use a negative margin - really, all sorts of things. And of course, it needs a higher `z-index` than the boxes.

Comment: JL, Just getting to look at this now our company was just bought so its all a bit distracting. I'll give feedback shortly.